# Mostrar estados en botón

Tags: php, pdo

saludos amigos estoy tratando de mostrar los estados en un botón de acuerdo a lo registrado en la bd, ejemplo tengo tres registros los cuales 2 están activo entonces en estos dos registro el botón debe estar activo y en el ultimo registro ya que esta fuera de servicio el botón debe estar disable, pero no logro lo requerido. gracias anexo código.

```
<?php if($linea['id_estados']){  // campo igual 1 true 
?>

<a class="btn"  value="<?php echo $linea['id_estados']; ?>">Operación</a>

<?php } else { //Si no es uno
?>

 <a class="btn disabled"  value="<?php echo $linea['id_estados']; ? 
 >">Operación</a>

  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yoclens, lo puedes resolver con un ternario de este modo:

```
/*Guardas un status de disabled o no*/
$status=(isset($linea["id_estados"]) && $linea["id_estados"]==1) ? "" : " disabled";

/*Guardas el valor puesto que también lo necesitarás*/
$valor=$linea["id_estados"];

/*Escribes todo en una variable, para más claridad*/
$html="<a class=\"btn$status\"  value=\"$valor\">Operación</a>";

/*La imprimes*/
echo $html;
```

Hagamos dos pruebas con valores distintos:

```
/*Prueba 1*/
$linea=array("id_estados"=>1);
$status=(isset($linea["id_estados"]) && $linea["id_estados"]==1) ? "" : "disabled";
$valor=$linea["id_estados"];
$html="<a class=\"btn$status\"  value=\"$valor\">Operación</a>";
echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```
<a class="btn"  value="1">Operación</a>
```

---

```
/*Prueba 2*/
$linea=array("id_estados"=>0);
$status=(isset($linea["id_estados"]) && $linea["id_estados"]==1) ? "" : " disabled";
$valor=$linea["id_estados"];
$html="<a class=\"btn$status\"  value=\"$valor\">Operación</a>";
echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```
<a class="btn disabled"  value="0">Operación</a>
```

**Nótese** que aquí **`" disabled"`** hay un espacio en blanco a la izquierda.

Si se tratase de varios valores, funcionaría igual, leyendo cada valor en un `foreach`, sólo que en ese caso habría que ir concatenando los resultados a la variable `$html`. Tenemos de ese modo un código limpio, claro, sencillo y funcional.

Comment: gracias @A. Cedano pero me falto algo como dijo el amigo jjcc, que es agregar la funcionalidad al boton osea pulsar y que por medio de esa consulta muestre los resultados en otra pagina pero el problema es que el boton disable asi muestre el estado inactivo lleva a la otra pagina lo he compuesto asi: /*Escribes todo en una variable, para más claridad*/
$html="<a href=\"alquilar.php?id_habitacon=$linea[id_habitacion]\"><button class=\"btn$status\"  value=\"$valor\">Operación</button>";

Comment: gracias ya lo resolví muchas gracias

Comment: @yoclens de acuerdo. Lo dejé tal como lo tenías con `a` porque pensé que estabas usando algo como bootstrap  o fontawesome o algo así. Pero cambiar el elemento es lo de menos una vez implementada la lógica, tal y como has hecho. Me alegro de que te haya funcionado.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la etiqueta `<button type="button"></button>` y no la de **hiperlink** `<a href="#"></a>` ya que si das clic sobre la etiqueta **hiperlink** aunque tenga la propiedad **disabled** `<a href="#" disabled></a>` el evento clic siempre se ejecuta mientras que si usas la etiqueta **button**  el evento clic no se ejecuta, esto es en el caso que quieras agregar funcionalidad al estado.

```
<?php
 if($linea['id_estados']==1){  // campo igual 1 true 
     echo '<a class="btn"  value="'.$linea['id_estados'].'">Operación</a>';
 }else{
     echo '<a class="btn disabled"  value="'.$linea['id_estados'].'">Operación</a>';
 }
?>
```

Saludos

Comment: gracias me a servido tu ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer todo en codigo pho incluso las etiquetas para no confundirte, y no estas imprimiendo un boton sino un link para el boton has lo siguiente:

```
<?php
 $linea['id_estados']= true;
 if ($linea['id_estados']) {
  echo "<button type='button' 
  $linea[id_estados]>operacion</button>";
  }else { //Si no es uno
   echo  "<button type='button' disabled value 
   ='$linea[id_estados]'>operacion</button>";
  }
 ?>
```